# What does button 2 mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What does "button 2" mean in the Minecraft controls list?

Answer (score 10):

Typically, unless the control scheme of a game specifically mentions a gamepad/joystick, "Button #" refers to the mouse;

- Button 1 is your ***left*** mouse button
- Button 2 is your ***right*** mouse button
- Button 3 is your ***middle*** mouse button

  - In most modern mice, this involves pressing down on the mouse wheel between the left and right buttons.
- some mice may have more buttons, but most games will not have their default controls bound to more than three buttons on the mouse.

Answer (score 4):

Button 2 is your right-mouse button.

Comment: Why downvote? It's the correct answer!